# Using query/import range to combine multiple columns from Workbook A into one column in Workbook B in same order

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have one Workbook A where a client will fill in either column A or B with a value (if there's something in A1, B1 will be empty, etc.), and I'd like to connect it to Workbook B in one column. It's important to keep the data in the original order from Workbook A in Workbook B, so a simple semicolon between the query functions won't work because it will put the values from row B after row A rather than "zipping" them in the same order as Workbook B.

Is there a way to easily do this? I'm thinking it may be possible with query/import range but am of course open to other options. Also maybe important to note that column A will contain only numerical values, and column B will contain a combination of numbers and letters.

Here's a link to a sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Qf5gKSqFawr7Uo7NEO6gtxACRxBTtksrJ7m_PNkhyk/edit#gid=1372521521

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flatten()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( query( flatten(trim(A3:B)), "where Col1 is not null", 0 ) )`

If you are importing the data from another spreadsheet file, replace `A3:B` with `importrange("...", "Sheet1!A3:B")`.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much! Not really familiar with flatten, will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Import the range from the client spreadsheet using `IMPORTRANGE`. Of course, you need permission to access the data.

Let's assume that you import the data as show in columns A and B of your question. Then insert this formula in Cell D3

`=ARRAYFORMULA(A3:A11&B3:B11)`

---

**Sample**

[image]